# Need help for join and some calculations on a MySql insert

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'll try to provide some context so you can understand what I'm trying to achieve here. My company uses open source software to manage the employees leaves (Jorani, feel free to google it :) ).

There are different types of leave (holidays, sick leave, etc.) and we want to calculate the days "not used" from the holidays of 2016 and "copy" them to another type of leave called "Remaining Holidays 2016".

The important tables are:

**entitleddays** (here you specify how many days of each type you give to an employee)

```
id      employee    startdate   enddate     type    days    description
661     3           2016-01-01  2017-02-28  1       14.00   Holidays 2016
1296    3           2016-01-01  2016-12-31  4       18.00   Sick leave 2016
```

**leaves** (this table has information about the leaves taken by the employees)

```
id      startdate   enddate     status  employee    cause               duration    type
2436    2016-08-01  2016-08-01  3       78          OK from managers    1.00        1
2766    2016-09-05  2016-09-12  3       63          Holidays            6.00        1
```

So basically we have:

**Entitled leaves:**
Data stored in the entitleddays table shown above. In our example let's say I have 14 days for my 2016 holidays.

**Taken leaves:**
Leaves taken by the user, stored in the table called leaves shown above. For our example let's say I took a day off the first of August and 6 days on September.

**Available leaves:**
Available days are calculated: entitled days minus "taken leaves". For this examplee, 14 entitled days - 7 = 7 days. So I still have seven days available for holidays :D

So my goal is to insert these 7 days for this user as entitled days for the new type: "Remaining days from 2016" and do this for every user. So the solution that comes up to my mind is to do something like this for every user:

```
INSERT INTO entitleddays (employee, startdate, enddate, type, days, description) 
    SELECT id, '2017-01-01', '2017-02-31', '8', (entitled holidays for 2016 minus all the taken leaves of this type), 'Remaining holidays from 2016'
    FROM users
```

Where 8 is the new type of leave where I want to copy the days (Remaining holidays from 2016).

For example I can get the taken holidays from 2016 for a specific user doing this:

```
SELECT SUM(duration)
FROM leaves
WHERE employee=3 AND status=3 AND type=1
```

Note: Type 1 is the type of leave "Holidays 2016" and status 3 means that the leave request was accepted.

I can probably achieve all of this in a single SQL instruction but it can also be split in more if simpler or easiest to manage/understand.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: wha acutally you want expected result ?

Comment: What is `type` in `entitleddays`? Do we have to consider the different types and the date-fields?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale Bhosale not sure if I understand you. Do you want me to clarify the expected result?

Comment: I don't understand why this is something you'd 'store' rather than just calculate on-the-fly?!?!

Comment: @Philipp I left a note in my question: Where "8" is the new type of leave where I want to copy the days (Remaining holidays from 2016).

Not sure if is was clear enough, but we can just consider the type 8, no need to dig deeper into that :)

About the dates, we just need the two I'm using in my INSERT ('2017-01-01' and '2017-02-31').

Comment: @Strawberry that's what I was asked for and what I need, to store the available days in the new type. Think of it as a "snapshot" of the actual state of the holidays.

Comment: I wouldn't normally store a 'snapshot' either!

Comment: @Strawberry haha! The point is that the software doesn't carry over the leaves from one year to the next one. We need to keep the "unused" days from 2016 so the employees can use them until the end of February of 2017. So we will copy the actual count to the new type "Remaining leaves from 2016" and when the employees use these days we will subtract the days from both leaves (so they can use them now on 2016 and also at the beginning of 2017). It's a workaround, maybe not the better one but it should work.

Comment: (It's none of my business, but a simpler workaround might be to insist that employees use up their leave entitlement before the end of the year)

Comment: So does leave entitlement run from January until the end of February in the following year?

Comment: We'll try to keep the rights of the employees! Hehe. Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can handle the calculation:

- sum the entitleddays in a subquery by grouping the datasets in its table per employee

  - maybe even group by year? In this case I just filtered for 2016 via `WHERE`-clause
- sum the taken holidays in a subquery, again by grouping per employee

  - group by year or filter directly for the one you need
- join this subquery onto the other resultset of the other query
- calculate (entitled days - taken leaves) in the outer query

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    entitled.employee,
    '2017-01-01',
    '2017-02-31',
    '8' AS type,
    entitled.days - takenDays.days,
    'Remaining holidays from 2016'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            employee,
            SUM(days) AS days
        FROM
            entitleddays
        WHERE
            startdate >= '2016-01-01'
        AND type = 1
        GROUP BY
            employee
    ) AS entitled
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        employee,
        SUM(duration) AS days
    FROM
        `leaves`
    WHERE
        startdate >= '2016-01-01'
    AND type = 1
    GROUP BY
        employee
) AS takenDays ON takenDays.employee = entitled.employee
```

I am not sure if this is how you want to calculate the sums for the days of entitleddays and taken days. The query just checks if `startdate >= '2016-01-01'`.

Also you mentioned a table `users` in your attempt but didn't provide details for the table, so I left it out. I guess you could use it as a basis otherwise. In the current query the grouped result of `entitleddays` is the basis.

**For the insert**

```
INSERT INTO entitleddays (employee, startdate, enddate, type, days, description) 
    SELECT
        entitled.employee,
        '2017-01-01',
        '2017-02-31',
        '8' AS type,
        entitled.days - takenDays.days,
        'Remaining holidays from 2016'
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                employee,
                SUM(days) AS days
            FROM
                entitleddays
            WHERE
                startdate >= '2016-01-01'
            AND type = 1
            GROUP BY
                employee
        ) AS entitled
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            employee,
            SUM(duration) AS days
        FROM
            `leaves`
        WHERE
            startdate >= '2016-01-01'
        AND type = 1
        GROUP BY
            employee
    ) AS takenDays ON takenDays.employee = entitled.employee
```

Comment: Thank you @Philipp! This is pretty close to what I want. I modified a few things: removed the startdate from the WHERE clauses and in the second SELECT I added in the WHERE: "AND status = 3" (this means, sum the duration of the accepted leave requests only). This SELECT gets the data I need, but I would like to insert it into entitleddays as in the example of my original post, any idea about how could I do that? Thank you very much again!

Comment: It should work with the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax you tried in your example. Just needed the corrext query